# Can i have multiple OSses on a memory stick?

Tags: partitioning, operating-systems, memorystick

I have a memory stick which I want to partition and install both ubuntu and fedora. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create multiple partitions on a memory stick.

Just proceed as usual, you might want to pre-partition from your OS rather than from the intallation...

Comment: @TomWijsman: Don't try *too* hard to get the mod tools, it was a bit underwhelming when I got it on SO. :P

Comment: @Mehrdad: I already have them by now. :)

Comment: @TomWijsman: Oh whoops, I thought you meant the 20k one, never mind. Gratz on the 10k ones! :)